# Error in project setup on ubuntu environment

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

[image: Terminal output]

when I'm trying to set up the opensource project oppia I get this error when running python -m scripts.start

chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink '/media/rajitha/ubuntu Data/opensource/oppia/.git/hooks/pre-commit'

can someone help me with this

Comment: Its best to ask this question in the [oppia community chat](https://gitter.im/oppia/oppia-chat), they might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is pretty clear: you have a dangling symlink `/media/rajitha/ubuntu Data/opensource/oppia/.git/hooks/pre-commit`. (A dangling symlink is a symlink that points to a non-existing file). The message "Symlink already exists" suggests that you've already tried the commands with an error.

Remove the symlink `/media/rajitha/ubuntu Data/opensource/oppia/.git/hooks/pre-commit` and try the command again.